# If X is uniformly distributed over $(-1, 1)$, find $P(|X| \gt \frac12)$

Tags: probability, random-variables

If X is uniformly distributed over $(-1, 1)$, find $P(|X| \gt \frac12 )$

I know what the pdf looks like, it is $0$ when $x \gt 1$ and $x \lt -1$, and when $-1 \lt x \lt 1$ it is a constant $\frac12$.
if the question was asking for $P(X \gt \frac12)$ I would do $\int_\frac12^1 \frac12 dx$ and get the answer $\frac14$, but because there is an absolute value around the X in the question I don't know what to do?
Do I have to calculate two integrals and add them?
$\int_\frac12^1 \frac12 dx$ and $\int_{-1}^{-\frac12} \frac12 dx$?

Comment: Yes, you should go with the approach you have mentioned.  But clean up your integrals - they don't look right.

Comment: why $\int x dx$? lets start from here

Comment: You are overcomplicating this.  For uniform distribution, evaluating the probability $P(X \gt \frac{1}{2})$ only needs the integral $\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 \frac{1}{2} \;dx$, and instead of "integrating" per se, you only need the length of the interval $(1/2,1)$ in proportion to $(-1,1)$.  Now consider the union of intervals where $|X|\gt \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: I fixed the intervals, I put the x there beause I got confused with the formula of expectation of a pdf

Comment: hardmath, the union of intervals where $|X| \gt \frac12$ is the length of the interval $(\frac12, 1)$ and the length of the interval $(-1, {-\frac12})$, this is the same thing as what I am saying in my integrals correct?

Comment: @idknuttin Correct.  This only works with uniform distributions, though, but it is good to understand the basics.

Comment: A question though, is the $\Box$ symbol meant to be something, or just a typo? @idknuttin

Comment: that symbol means end of proof, but I didn't use that, I don't know where you see that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.   You must integrate over the two disjoined intervals of the support where the absolute value of the random variable are greater than an half.   *Linearity of Integration* means you may sum the integrals over each.

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(\lvert X\rvert > \tfrac 1 2)
 & = \displaystyle\int_{\{x\in(-1;1):\lvert x\rvert>1/2\}} f_X(x)\operatorname d x
\\[1ex] & = \int_{(-1;-1/2)\cup(1/2;1)}\tfrac 1 2\operatorname d x
\\[1ex] &  = \int_{-1}^{-1/2} \tfrac 1 2\operatorname d x+ \int_{1/2}^1 \tfrac 12\operatorname d x
\end{align}$$

Which, as hardmath commented, doesn't actually need any calculus to find.   This is because the *constant* density means we just need to compare interval lengths.   [**Important!**: the distribution must be *uniform* for this to work.]

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(\lvert X\rvert > \tfrac 1 2)
& = \frac{\lvert(-1;-1/2)\cap(1/2;1)\rvert}{\lvert(-1;-1/2)\cap(1/2;1)\rvert}{\lvert(-1;1)\rvert}
\\[1ex] & = \tfrac 1 2
\end{align}$$

But there's nothing wrong with ensuring you've mastered the concept before moving onto *non-uniform* distributions.   Good work.

Comment: if I wanted to find the density function of random variable |X| would it simply be this?   f(|X|) =
\begin{cases}
\frac12,  & \text{if $x$ is in [0, 1)} \\
0, & \text{else}
\end{cases}

Comment: Not quite, @idknuttin  Remember that the absolute signage folds two intervals into one. $$f_{\lvert X\rvert}(x) = \big(f_X(x)+f_X(-x)\big) \mathbf 1_{x\in [0;1)} = \begin{cases}1 & : x\in [0;1) \\ 0 &: \textsf{otherwise} \end{cases}$$ As a reality check: the integral of the pdf over the support must equal unity.